# Should I use "report" or "complaint" in the context of website content flagging?

Tags: word-choice

I'm translating a confirmation email to english. This email is sent to the website's user when he flags a content as inappropriate or offensive.

Something like:

> We have received your (**report** / **complaint**) at our website.

So, what word is the most suitable in this case? Or is there yet another alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with "report". "Complaint" would apply if it were only a confirmation about offensive things, but to make it broad enough to cover both inappropriate (perhaps off-topic, but not scandalous) and offensive, use the more neutral "report".